# What do I need to do to load a bootstrap example using Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've installed my first meteor packages this evening.  All I'm trying to do is further the leaderboard example a little further by incorporating it into the less version of bootstrap.

Specifically I want to use this bootstrap example layout (I basically just copied the html):

[bootstrap jumbotron example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/)

I've been following this tutorial:

[Meteor.js and Twitter Bootstrap - The right way](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way)

When I try to start the app I get:

```
> $ meteor
[[[[[ ~/bootstrapApp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
bootstrapApp.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
bootstrapApp.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I removed the doctype and that's when I got the bad formatting error.

I don't know what Meteor does when it comes to rendering a bootstrap html page.  Obviously CSS and JS will be in different directories and so won't be loaded.

Can anyone show me how to get this page loaded properly?  This I expect is extremely simple, curse of the newbie!

I'm not sure exactly where the meteor template code should go, I just placed them after the closing html element.

Thank you in advance for anything that helps me get this going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to include the content of the body tag in the jumbotron example. Meteor does the rest for you.

Here it is with the head and script tags stripped out. Put this in your template and it should work.

https://gist.github.com/nmacmunn/e45ec29654efa7893b59

Comment: I cloned that file and and moved it to /bootstrapApp/bootstrapApp.html

I've still getting that error:

Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
bootstrapApp.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.



I'm not sure what the problem is.  If it helps this is the contents of my app:

$ ls
bootstrapApp.css  bootstrapApp.html  bootstrapApp.js  client  e45ec29654efa7893b59  packages  smart.json  smart.lock

Comment: Got it working now :)  Just wrapped your example in body tags and that sorted it.  Thank you for your help :)